# Decimal Point button is missing from Keyboard

Tags: android, xml, decimal-point

I have a custom dialog with a few text views, edit texts, image buttons etc in a Table Layout. I have two table rows, each having a text view and an edit text with input type numberDecimal for first and numberDecimal|numberSigned for next. When focus comes into etMiscUnitSale, decimal point button is present in keyboard, but not for etMiscUnitCost. This is a problem for a very few clients and it works fine in all the devices I tested. I cannot test or debug in those devices which are having this issue. Most of the devices which have this issue are with OS version is 4.1.2

This is the code in Layout file

```
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/trMiscUnitSale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMiscUnitSale"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="Unit Sale : "
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="serif" >
                </TextView>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etMiscUnitSale"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="0.00"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:typeface="serif" >
                </EditText>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/trMiscUnitCost"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMiscUnitCost"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="Unit Cost : "
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="serif" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etMiscUnitCost"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="0.00"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
                    android:typeface="serif" />
            </TableRow>
```

I had experimented by giving android:digits="0123456789." etc. but nothing worked. is it a problem of OS version? Please help...